# UIPopover not appearing in correct place

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Using this code; The iPad UIPopover appears at the top of the screen, not above the button from which it was pressed - I know Apple reject apps for that, so is there a way to make it so that it appears above the button that was pressed?
This is the current code to call it;

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)picker];
        CGRect takePhotoRect;
        takePhotoRect.origin = self.view.frame.origin;
        takePhotoRect.size.width = 1;
        takePhotoRect.size.height = 1;
        [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 216.0)];

        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:takePhotoRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:takePhotoRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

method, use the frame of the button, like:

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:myButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help. Accepting the answer is the customary thank you around here :)

Comment: No problem, I just did ( I had to wait a few moments before it would let me mark it as answered - testament to your response being faster than the speed of sound! Haha :) thank you again!